# Viewing content of http body from apache2 logging

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-httpd, logs, http

so I am sending custom http post/get/put requests to my apache2 server and I would like to log exactly what is received by the server. So far I am using ForensicLog module and that allows me to see most stuff like content type, body length, header, but not body content. How would I be able to see this information?

```
Protocol = Http
Method = Post
Port = 80
Http Body = testbody
Http Header = testheader, value: 222


root@pc44:/var/log/apache2# cat forensic_log.log +22875:5ab9615a:0|POST / HTTP/1.1|Host:172.18.64.136|Accept:*/*|testheader:222|Content-Length:8|Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded-22875:5ab9615a:0
```

Answer (score 1):

you can capture traffic with tcpdump.
Then you can decode file with Tshark tool to get all fields which is need to be sent.